# expand and collapse View functionality in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Category 1 (Level 1)
- Subcategory 1 (Level 2)
----Sub-Subcategory 2 (Level 3)
-----Sub-subcategory 3 (Level 3)
Category 2 (Level 1)
- Subcategory 2 (Level 2)
- Subcategory 3 (Level 2)
-----Sub-subcategory 4 (Level 3)
------Subcategory 5 (Level 3)
```

For Example 1:

```
Tangible Assets (Level 1)
-.Vehicles      (Level 2)
----Staff Vehicles (Level 3)
----Cars 
- Computers & Electronics (Level 2)
-----Cash Counting Machine (Level 3)
----Computer & Electronics (Level 3)
----Computer Software      (Level 3)
```

Show Record Level 1 click the Level 1 display Level 2 then click the Level 2 display Level 3

Comment: any code? what did you try so far?

Comment: Can you try [ui-tree](https://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/)?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part when building a tree like structure is directive recursion. Google for "recursive directive" to find some info about the problems. The solution is to add and compile the recursive parts in `link`. I've built a simple example here http://plnkr.co/edit/JgQu3r?p=preview

```
function myMenu() {
    return {
      scope : {
        myMenu : '=myMenu'
      },
      template: '<li ng-repeat="item in myMenu"><my-menu-item></my-menu-item></li>'
    }
}

myMenuItem.$inject = ['$compile'];
function myMenuItem($compile) {
    return {
      template: '<a href ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="show($event)"></a>',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        if (angular.isArray(scope.item.menu)) {
              element.append($compile(
                '<ul ng-if="collapsed" my-menu="item.menu"></ul>')(scope));

        }
        scope.show = function($event) {
          scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;
        }
      }
    }
}
```