# Duplicate element ID when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website that would display multiple collapsible list (e.g. categories & sub categories), so far I have managed to create dynamic divs using ng-repeat but my problem is when toggling the collapse. In the second category, when trying to toggle to display/hide the list, it toggles the list on the first div instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <div ng-repeat="cat in categories"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" class="img-circle center-block img-responsive" height="75" width="75">
                </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-8">
                <b>
                    {{cat}}
                </b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items ">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12"> 
                <p ng-click="toggleCollapse($index + 1)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    {{item}} 
                </p>
                <div id="collapse{{ $index + 1}}" class="collapse collapse-checklist">
                    <div ng-repeat="c in checklist">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.toggleCollapse = function (ind) {
    var collapseInd = ("#collapse" + ind);
    $(collapseInd).collapse('toggle');
};
```

Now, I have identified that the problem is ng-repeat creates the div with the same ID(collapse**i**) which causes the function on the second div toggle the list on the first div instead.

My function works well in the first *cat* div, but on all other div, it still toggles the list on the first div. Can anyone help me fix my function so it would toggle the lists on its respective div?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238321/expand-and-collapse-view-functionality-in-angularjs

Comment: Why not use ng-hide/ng-show instead of jquery? I would not recommend using jquery in an angular app (and it is definitely not necessary). You could hide/show the elements on click without much hassle using angular.

Comment: ^This. Thanks. It didn't worked when I first tried it but I am now able to toggle the content using angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by tudor-gergely.

Used angular approach.

```
<p ng-click="showChecklist = !showChecklist"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        {{item}}
                    </p>
                <div ng-show="showChecklist">
                    <div ng-repeat="c in checklist">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can avoid using ID by calling collapse on next div element. See below code

```
$scope.toggleCollapse = function (ind) {
    $(this).next('div.collapse.collapse-checklist').collapse('toggle');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some duplicate id by using `ng-repeat`, you should probably use it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

So, now you will see that `key` will be changed every-time. And making some custom id.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td id="myCustomId_{{key}}"> {{key}} </td>
  <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

you will get a unique id.

This method is listed in the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat